# Apache ProxyPass error

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxypass

I have to redirect all apache requests on 80 to tomcat on 8080, except one path.

So, if a receive http://example.com/anything --> tomcat:8080.

But, if the url is that: http://example.com/site --> apache should serve and no redirect is needed.

Currently, there is a folder named `site` inside `/var/www/html/`.

This is my current configuration file:

***site.conf*** *(this file contains only the following and is inside the conf.d folder)*

```
<LocationMatch "/*">
        Allow from all
        ProxyPass               /site !  
        ProxyPass               http://127.0.0.1:8080
        ProxyPassReverse        http://127.0.0.1:8080
</LocationMatch>
```

I think this is a simple thing to accomplish with apache, but I have tried everything that I could find and I am still getting the error:

```
ProxyPass|ProxyPassMatch can not have a path when defined in a location.
```

The thing is that the root website is running on tomcat, but the other runs on apache (the one that I called *site* in this question).

If anyone can help, I appreciate.

Thanks!

**Update 1 - 09/06/2017**

I get it to work if I remove the `LocationMatch` and put the `ProxyPass`
direct in the `.conf` file:

```
ProxyPass               /site !
ProxyPassReverse        /site !
ProxyPass               / http://127.0.0.1:8080
ProxyPassReverse        / http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

But, I would like to know, why is that? What is the impact of putting this directives outside the `LocationMatch` tag? And, most important, why I cannot accomplish the same result using the `LocationMatch`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the error is pretty clear:

```
ProxyPass|ProxyPassMatch can not have a path when defined in a location.
```

According to [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass), inside a context block like `Location` or `LocationBlock` the `ProxyPass` directive does not accept a path:

> When used inside a `<Location>` section, the first argument is omitted and the local directory is obtained from the `<Location>`. The same will occur inside a `<LocationMatch>` section; however, ProxyPass does not interpret the regexp as such, so it is necessary to use ProxyPassMatch in this situation instead.

You're getting the error because you were trying to use a path:

```
ProxyPass               /site !
```

You could try to resolve this in theory by using multiple `<Location>` sections, like this:

```
<Location />
    ProxyPass http://backend/
</Location>

<Location /site>
    ProxyPass !
</Location>
```

The [ordering of these sections is important](https://serverfault.com/questions/391457/how-does-apache-merge-multiple-matching-location-sections).

Your solution of using `ProxyPass` directives outside of a `LocationMatch` block is probably the simplest solution.

---

As a side note, your `LocationMatch` directive is incorrect.  The argument to `LocationMatch` is a regular expression, and `/*` would only match URLs consisting only of `/` characters.  That is, it would match `/` or `//` or `/////////`, etc.  I think you really meant `/.*`.  The `*` in a regular expression means "the previous character, zero or more times".

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thanks! I will try your solution using `Location`. But, by not using a `Location`, what are the difference? Setting these proxy values direct in the file is the same as setting for the `VirtualHost` itself or the `Directory`? There is any problems with that approach?

Comment: I'm not sure there's much of a difference using `Location` vs. just using `ProxyPass` at the top level of the config file if you're only using the `Location` block to set `ProxyPass`.  I guess if you were doing more in the `Location` section than just `ProxyPass` you might prefer to keep related configuration elements together.